# Xamarin.Forms: Could not start Xamarin.Forms Hot Reload session

Tags: hot-reload, visual-studio-mac-2022

I am working on a Xamarin project and HotReload does not work anymore since VS2022 Mac, it worked with VS2019 Mac. When I start the app on iOS Simulator I see the following message in XAML Hot Reload Window:

```
Could not start Xamarin.Forms Hot Reload session
```

Hot reload is enabled in VS2022 for Mac:
[image]

On Android it does not work either, it says:

```
XAML Hot Reload is disabled because your Android Linker settings are unsupported. Set Linker Behaviour to "Don't Link" and rebuild your project...
```

But the Linker Behaviour is already set to "Don't Link".

1. HotReload works fine when running a **new** Xamarin.Forms or MAUI
   project.
2. I have opened the VS log files and searched for HotReload
   but I don't find any errors.
3. I tried the 'Full page' option
4. I went through [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/hot-reload)
5. The project uses Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2515
6. I am using VS Mac 2022 17.4.2 and VS Mac 2022 17.5 Preview

**Does anybody how to troubleshoot this problem and what to look for where?**